# How to sniff HTTP response headers in Chrome? for "attachment" content?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Usually I'm able to sniff my HTTP requests using Chrome Dev Tools - network tab.

But it's not happening for download-files (i.e. when `Content-Dsiplosition` is set to `Attachment;filename=xxx`) - then Chrome just downloads the file and nothing is shown on the network tab.

How do I see those? I mean, in Chrome, without any 3rd party tools like PostMan.

PS. I need to see the headers my server sends, there's some debugging info I need.

Comment: If the network panel doesn't show it, maybe it's still visible for an extension that uses webRequest API. [Poke the webstore](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/sniffer?_category=extensions)

Answer (score 14):

When I try to paste an URL pointing to a downloadable file, directly into the browser address, it doesn't show anything on the network tab.

However, I've found a workaround that suits my use case. Create an .html file anywhere, and just create a link to that attachment (an alternative is to just open `about:blank` in the browser and edit the HTML in place).

`<a href="https://example.com/example.ambiguous.file">download</a>`

Then open that .html file and click on the link.

This causes the network tab to display the file you're trying to download, and so the headers.

In my case I was able to troubleshoot how the `Content-Disposition` headers was never sent to specific browsers.

---

EDIT (2017-11):

If this doesn't work with recent versions of Chrome, try putting it in an image tag. The objective is to sniff the HTTP response headers, not the content.

`<img src="https://example.com/example.ambiguous.file">download</img>`

Comment: @ViRuSTriNiTy I tried my answer and surprisingly I can't seem to make it work anymore. I have updated the answer with an alternative approach of putting it in an `img` tag. (I did not succeed with JavaScript `window.open`, and AJAX is blocked by CORS)

Answer (score 4):

You can view them in FireFox: F12 then Network tab

Comment: This indeed seems to be the easiest solution. You can cancel the download and look at headers.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution here is to use Postman Interceptor which will provide Chrome cookies. So just follow http://blog.getpostman.com/2014/11/28/using-the-interceptor-to-read-and-write-cookies/ and then paste that download link in Postman to see request and response details.

Answer (score -1):

You can view them from the Headers tab.

The response body itself is the file being downloaded and you will not be able to see it from the Response tab, but I can see the response headers from the Headers tab, check the picture:

[image]

Comment: My whole "network" tool is empty. There are no requests listed there

Comment: After opening network console, you've to refresh the page.

Comment: @shiva If you refresh the pdf page after opening the devtools (automatically in a new page), its closed by itself.

Comment: You will notice that `Set-Cookie` is always missing - and `view source` option itself is also now missing from Chrome completely.